# Run Jar file in command prompt on Linux Server

Tags: java, jar

How can we run Jar File in command prompt?

I've used this command:

```
java -jar myJARFile.jar
```

But the result was:

```
-bash: java: command not found
```

Comment: Have you installed a JRE on your system? Are you sure that the `java` binary is in your `PATH` variable?

Comment: How do I install? jre

Comment: Check this link to find out how to install Java: http://bit.ly/1lI9gAS

Comment: the installation of java depends on your linux distribution and the jre/jdk vendor. here is an example to of installing sun/oracle jre/jdk on redhat/fedora/centos http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-sun-oracle-java-jdk-jre-7-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Comment: To implement this
  What do I need in Linux      3. To generate Standart Unlimited License key use our tool from 'keygen' dir: java -jar keygen.jar

Answer (score 1):

You need to install java on your machine and add the java directory to PATH variable.